# What does it mean to `Muse through a document"?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-usage, synonyms

I remember I learned this word "muse" while listening to a vocabulary builder audiobook.

I believe it meant "to go through a document very carefully".

I tried to google the meaning of the word but I could not find anything except "a person or personified force who is the source of inspiration for a creative artist.".

I also have used this word in several emails (I emailed: "I will reply soon after musing through the document"). I feel like this is not the spelling of the word or I heard something wrong.

Is there another word that expresses that someone is reading a document very carefully and with attention?

Comment: *Muse* means to think about or comment thoughtfully about something. I don't think "muse through the document" makes sense, but you could say, "I will reply after [*perusing*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/peruse) the document".

Comment: Your email might work better like this: *I will reply soon, after I've had an opportunity to read through the document and do some musing.*  Note that in general, we can say "muse about" or "muse over" or just "muse" by itself, but I've never seen "muse through."  "Read through," yes.  You can also say "peruse the document carefully" but it sounds just a bit pompous or stilted. // When you looked up "muse," somehow you missed the verb definition.

Comment: The funny thing is that muse and peruse are almost rhymes. But not quite. So one can see why they might recall each other...

Comment: It’s really quite charming!  You could also *amuse* your way through or *bemuse* your way through. I hadn’t realised that this word was so versatile.

Comment: Yes that makes sense thank you. i will use it in case where i want to imply that i am deeply thinking about something.

Also perusing is a new word for me today. Thanks.

Comment: @aparente001.  I just realised that there is a arrow that revealed the verb part of the word in google defination. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When used with an object and in conjunction with the preposition "through" like it is there, the verb "[muse](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/muse?s=t)" is used to mean "meditate upon" or "comment or ruminate thoughtfully on."

**Examples  of this usage from published works:**

> "A huge bull mused through the assembly of cows and heifers."

-*Son of Adam* by Frederick Manfred, [pg. 250](https://books.google.com/books?id=KfANAAAAIAAJ&q=%22mused%20through%22&dq=%22mused%20through%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjX8NfHh7XkAhVjFjQIHWtODkc4ChDoAQhAMAQ)

> "He mused though a stack of invoices on his desk..."

-*Straight Through the Night* by Edward Allen, [pg. 101](https://books.google.com/books?id=eCpaAAAAMAAJ&q=%22mused%20through%22&dq=%22mused%20through%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjX8NfHh7XkAhVjFjQIHWtODkc4ChDoAQg6MAM)

> "I stood for a long time looking at the razorlike weapon in my hand,
>   while Dart mused through his arsenal..."

-Through the Lens" by Morrell Massey, [pg. 23](https://books.google.com/books?id=DbVWAAAAYAAJ&q=%22mused%20through%22&dq=%22mused%20through%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHq7zbiLXkAhUFoZ4KHflIB404FBDoAQhUMAg)

Answer (score 2):

As in:

*With the document in hand, he [**mused**] reflected upon it deeply, considering all of its ramifications*

**muse**  [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/muse)

- > to reflect upon deeply

You can't muse in five seconds. People muse on certain ideas for years. Muse can also refer to thinking deeply. If you muse on or about something, you're giving it serious thought.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatives to “muse” as a verb include read carefully, read thoughtfully, analyze, and so forth.

The use of muse as a verb has, to me, a connotation of creative rumination rather than analysis or rational judgment, perhaps because the word is usually used as a noun to refer to an inspirational person in the life of a creative artist.

For example, Camille Claudel was Auguste Rodin’s “muse and mistress.” http://www.musee-rodin.fr/en/resources/educational-files/rodin-and-camille-claudel#muse